# How to list all the entries of a tar file in java?

Tags: java, list, file, tar

I want to list all the entries of a tar file in my Java program. How is it possible ?
For zip files, I can use the below code:

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("ReadZip.zip");
Enumeration entries = zf.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {.....}
```

But I am not sure for the tar files. Can anybody help? I am using `org.apache.tools.tar.*`

Answer (score 14):

[Apache Commons Compress (http://commons.apache.org/compress/)](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) is easy to use.

Here's an example of reading a tar's entries:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;

public class Taread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
            TarArchiveEntry entry;
            while (null!=(entry=tarInput.getNextTarEntry())) {
                System.out.println(entry.getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can list all the entries of Zip and tar.gz using TarArchieveInputStream and ZipInputStream using the seperate function but is there way to handle both in single function? something like 'case zip() =>  new ZipInputStream(src.open)
        case tar() => new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(file.open))

Answer (score 2):

This API is very similar to using Java's own [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

To start off:

```
TarInputStream tis = new TarInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.tar"));
try
{
    TarEntry entry;
    do
    {
        entry = tis.getNextEntry();

        //Do something with the entry
    }
    while (entry != null);
}
finally
{
    tis.close();
}

More examples with different APIs are [here][2].
```

Comment: Unfortunately you forgot to add a link(

Answer (score 0):

you were using the ZIP file code for listing the directories....

tar file for linux you can check out

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/TapeArchiveListerTarfile.htm

for further references....

Answer (score -3):

To read a Java .jar file, you can use the "jar" tool ... or Unzip.  .Jar files are in .Zip format.

To read a *nix .tar file, however, you need to use the "tar" tool.

If you're on Windows, I'd encourage you to try 7-Zip.  It's a handy tool that recognizes a zillion formats ... including both .zip (hence also .jar) and tar:

http://www.7-zip.org/

If you must do it programmatically, I guess the Apache Ant API "tar" is a good way to go.  It gives you a list of "TarEntry":

http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/ja/manual/api/org/apache/tools/tar/TarEntry.html